# Get environment variables as defined in Windows (not process specific)

Tags: java, cmd, windows-7, environment-variables

I am trying to build a Java application that can edit environment variables (if possible even differentiate between system variables and user variables), basically doing exactly the same thing as the Environment Variable Editor in Windows 7, just with an easier to use interface:
[image: Windows 7 Environment Variable Editor]

And yes, I am aware that there are applications out there doing exactly that, but I want to code it myself (as practice and for fun).

However my problem is that when getting these variables, it always returns the variables currently set in this process (see Example).

Is there a way to get the variables as they are set in Windows?

I tried starting a cmd.exe new process from java and executing [SET](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html), but the new process inherits the variables.

To persist them I thought I'd use the [SETX](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) command, but I haven't tested it yet.

I only need a solution for Windows 7, no need for it to be working with any other OS.

Example:

Path is: 'c:\apps\oracle\clients{...}\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\'

However in my Java Application it ends with 'java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin'.

JDK 1.8 is not in my global path variable and only there for the current process.

Comment: The `SET` command only affects the current process, so that's not what you want to use. The environment variables are stored in the Windows Registry and therefore you have to use utilities that can access it, such as `SETX` or `REG` commands. Or, better still, using the Win API - either through JNI or by using a language other than Java.

Comment: thanks for the answer, trying it out now and if it works I'll post the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Windows registry, as DodgyCodeException suggested.
To access it, I used JNA

Sample Code (using system variables, pass true for param 'user' to use user variables):

```
public static final String USER_VAR_PATH = "Environment";
public static final String SYSTEM_VAR_PATH = "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Get all system environment variables
    for(String systemVariableName : getAllEnvironmetVariables(false).keySet()){
        System.out.println(systemVariableName);
    }

    //print system environment variable 'OS'
    System.out.println(getEnvironmetVariable("OS", false));

    //write to the path variable (append a string)
    String addToPath = "";
    setEnvironmetVariable("Path", getEnvironmetVariable("Path", false) + addToPath, false);
}

public static TreeMap<String, Object> getAllEnvironmetVariables(boolean user){
    HKEY root = user ? WinReg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER : WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    String path = user ? USER_VAR_PATH : SYSTEM_VAR_PATH;
    return Advapi32Util.registryGetValues(root, path);
}

public static String getEnvironmetVariable(String key, boolean user){
    HKEY root = user ? WinReg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER : WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    String path = user ? USER_VAR_PATH : SYSTEM_VAR_PATH;
    try{
        return Advapi32Util.registryGetExpandableStringValue(root, path, key);
    }catch(Exception e){
        return Advapi32Util.registryGetStringValue(root, path, key);
    }
}

public static void setEnvironmetVariable(String key, String value, boolean user){
    HKEY root = user ? WinReg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER : WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    String path = user ? USER_VAR_PATH : SYSTEM_VAR_PATH;
    if(value.contains("%")){
        Advapi32Util.registrySetExpandableStringValue(root, path, key, value);
    }else{
        Advapi32Util.registrySetStringValue(root, path, key, value);
    }
}
```

There are two types of values used by the variables: `REG_SZ` and `REG_EXPAND_SZ`.

Both are strings, but the second one indicates that it contains other variables (like `%SystemRoot%\...`)

My handling for those two types should work, but is definitely not clean. If there is a better way, please tell me.

EDIT: You need [JNA](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna) and [JNA Platform](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna-platform) for this to work.
Imports are:

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg.HKEY;
```